# Passing tags to cucumber in scala tests

Tags: ruby, scala

I used to be able to pass tags from the command-line to cucumber to run specific scenarios in ruby i.e. `cucubmer --tag wip`

is there a way to do it from the command-line in scala.
I ve tried to do this but it doesn't seem to work.
`-Dcucubmer.options="--tags @wip"`

Answer (score 0):

According to [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs-2.10.2/manual/html/scalac.html) it should work to set the Java env variable:

> –Dproperty=value
>   Pass –Dproperty=value directly to the runtime system.

and [this](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/jvm) says cucumber looks at that:

> Configuration options can also be overridden and passed to any of the runners via the cucumber.options Java system property.

Of course, you'd need to spell "cucumber" correctly :)